# How to strip a text file into a single line, and then split that into a relevant list in python?

Tags: file-io, pygame, stripping

I'm a noob right now with pygame and I was wondering how to load a textfile, then strip that into a a single line. I believe that i would need to use the `.rstrip('/n')` function on my variable with the openned text file. But now, how do I turn this into a list? If I intentionally used two colons (::) to separate between my relevant pieces of information in the text file, how do I make it into a list with each list index being the contents in between two sets of ::? The purpose is to create save files in a menu GUI when closed, so is there a simpler way to save and open the contents of variables from one instance of the program to the next?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> "foo::bar::baz".split("::")
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

If you just want to save structured data, however, you might want to look at either the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) or [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) libraries. Both of them give ways to dump Python objects to files and then load them back out again.